# Terraform generate aws_ec2_tag for each shared subnet

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I've created subnets in one AWS account and shared them with another AWS account.

I'm using the following Terraform code to get the individual subnet info:

```
data "aws_subnets" "subnets" {
  filter {
    name   = "vpc-id"
    values = [var.vpc_id]
  }
}

data "aws_subnet" "subnet" {
  for_each = toset(data.aws_subnets.subnets.ids)
  id       = each.value
}
```

`data.aws_subnet.subnet` is a collection of all of the subnets with all of their information within. I want to use this to generate an aws_ec2_tag for each tag on each subnet. The purpose of this is to ensure that tags are the same between the source AWS account and the AWS account that I'm sharing the subnets with.

I've got this so far, but I'm running up against a wall:

```
resource "aws_ec2_tag" "subnet_tags" {
  provider          = aws.dst
  for_each = {
    for subnet_id, subnet in data.aws_subnet.subnet : subnet_id => {
      for tag_key, tag_value in subnet.tags : tag_key => tag_value
    }
  }

  resource_id = data.aws_subnet.subnet[each.key].id
  key = each.key
  value = each.value
}
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
╷
│ Error: Incorrect attribute value type
│
│  on main.tf line 52, in resource "aws_ec2_tag" "subnet_tags":
│  52:  value = each.value
│   ├────────────────
│   │ each.value is object with 7 attributes
│
│ Inappropriate value for attribute "value": string required.
```

Please help me recreate my tags for the shared subnets. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

### Your Data

You need to understand your data before you use it ...

best you can do is use some outputs:

```hcl
data "aws_subnets" "subnets" {
  filter {
    name   = "vpc-id"
    values = [var.vpc_id]
  }
}

data "aws_subnet" "subnet" {
  for_each = toset(data.aws_subnets.subnets.ids)
  id       = each.value
}

output "loop_tags" {
    value = {
        for subnet_id, subnet in data.aws_subnet.subnet : subnet_id => {
            for tag_key, tag_value in subnet.tags : tag_key => tag_value
        }
    }
}
```

In my test if we do a TF plan on that we get:

```txt
  + loop_tags   = {
      + subnet-00ef25ac05236191d = {
          + abc = "123"
          + ert = "678"
        }
      + subnet-0103d668dece0ab77 = {
          + def = "345"
        }
      + subnet-045ba40ac4d5a668c = {
          + abc = "123"
        }
    }
```

that is not something you can use in the aws_ec2_tag

---

### Combine Tags

So the first thing we need to do is combine all those tags...
I'm going to use a couple of terraform functions:

- `values` https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/values

> values takes a map and returns a list containing the values of the elements in that map.
>
> The values are returned in lexicographical order by their corresponding keys, so the values will be returned in the same order as their keys would be returned from keys.

- `merge` https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/merge

> merge takes an arbitrary number of maps or objects, and returns a single map or object that contains a merged set of elements from all arguments.
>
> If more than one given map or object defines the same key or attribute, then the one that is later in the argument sequence takes precedence. If the argument types do not match, the resulting type will be an object matching the type structure of the attributes after the merging rules have been applied.

```hcl
locals {
  combined_subnet_tags = merge(values(data.aws_subnet.subnet)[*].tags...)
}
```

that will give a unique list of all tags:

```txt
    {
      + abc = "123"
      + def = "345"
      + ert = "678"
    }
```

---

### Loops

The next challenge we have is that there is a list of subnets and also a list of unique tags, but the `resource "aws_ec2_tag"` can create only one at a time, so we can use a module for that:

```hcl
module "aws_ec2_tags" {
  for_each = data.aws_subnet.subnet
  source   = "./aws_ec2_tag"

  all_tags      = local.combined_subnet_tags
  resource_id   = each.key
  resource_tags = each.value.tags
}
```

that way we are looping over all subnets...

inside that module we need to do a couple of things:

- the subnets already have tags we don't need to add duplicates
- `setsubtract` is the function to use, but it expects parameters as specific data type so we need to do some intermediary conversions

```hcl
variable "all_tags" {
  type = map(string)
}

variable "resource_id" {
  type = string
}

variable "resource_tags" {
  type = map(string)
}

locals {
  a        = [for k, v in var.all_tags : { "${k}" : v }]
  b        = [for k, v in var.resource_tags : { "${k}" : v }]
  subtract = setsubtract(local.a, local.b)
  tags     = { for k, v in var.resource_tags : k => v }
}

resource "aws_ec2_tag" "subnet_tags" {
  for_each = local.tags

  resource_id = var.resource_id
  key         = each.key
  value       = each.value
}
```

---

### Full Code

https://github.com/heldersepu/hs-scripts/tree/master/TerraForm/aws_subnet_tags

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of merge and values. However, I don't need a unique list of all tags. I need the tags as well as the subnet id for each tag, because that's what aws_ec2_tag requires.

Comment: @KenJ I think I covered all that in my answer ... I did multiple edits adding more and more details

Comment: I appreciate your effort, however you don't need a separate module for this. I'm already in a module at this point. I'm waiting for somebody to post a solution using just locals.

Comment: @KenJ Certainly we don't need a extra module, We can go with many other approaches, but this way in my opinion we get much cleaner code

Answer (score 0):

I ended up chaining locals to get what I needed. I needed a unique key for each subnet/tag map for the for_each loop. It's not an elegant solution, but it works without any major changes to my module.

NOTE that with the same provider you'd just be duplicating tags for the same resources. I'm using a separate provider for the AWS account that I'm sharing the subnets with, hence `provider = aws.dst`.

```
data "aws_subnets" "subnets" {
  filter {
    name   = "vpc-id"
    values = [var.vpc_id]
  }
}

data "aws_subnet" "subnet" {
  for_each = toset(data.aws_subnets.subnets.ids)
  id       = each.value
}

locals {
  subnet_tags = {
        for subnet_id, subnet in data.aws_subnet.subnet : subnet_id => {
            for tag_key, tag_value in subnet.tags : tag_key => tag_value
        }
  }
  flat_tags = flatten([
    for key, value in local.subnet_tags : [
      for tag_key, tag_value in value : {
        unique_key = "${key}-${tag_key}"
        resource_id = key
        key = tag_key
        value = tag_value
      }
    ]
  ])
}

resource "aws_ec2_tag" "test" {
  provider = aws.dst
  for_each = {
    for tag in local.flat_tags : tag.unique_key => tag
  }

  resource_id = each.value.resource_id
  key = each.value.key
  value = each.value.value
}
```

Comment: Lazy code ... duplicating tags is bad, that will be unacceptable in most organizations

Comment: You should make sure that the tag is not already there before you add it, even if that is a separate provider